# Get data asynchronously from firebase and set state after the data is reached

Tags: reactjs, firebase, async-await, react-native

I'm using react-native and I want to get data from the firebase realtime database and set state of that data and then only then load the view, I don't want the user to see the data getting pushed and mapped on every load of the chat view.

Here is what I've tried

```
_getMessages = async () => {

    let message_array = [];

    await firebase.database().ref('User-Message').child(this.state.fromUser).child(this.state.toUser).on('child_added', async (snapshot) => {

      let message_id = await snapshot.key;

      let message_ref = await firebase.database().ref('Message').child(message_id).once('value', async (payload) => {

        await message_array.push(payload.val())

      })

      await this.setState({ messages : message_array })

    })

}
```

And in my `componentWillMount` is simply call the `_getMessages()` function like this

```
componentWillMount = async () => {

    await this._getMessages();

}
```

How can I make sure to set the state of messages after getting all the messages from the firebase?

Comment: Are you using any sort of state management? Redux or Mobx would make this a lot simpler.

Comment: no i'm not .. and it's my first project in react-native which i have to deliver tomorrow so i don't have any time left to try redux ..

Answer (score 1):

This won't work:

```
await firebase.database().ref('User-Message').child(this.state.fromUser).child(this.state.toUser).on('child_added', async (snapshot) => {
```

Firebase's `on()` method starts actively listening for events. It does not have a clear moment when it's done, so doesn't return a promise. Hence it can't be used with `await`/`async`.

My feeling is that you're trying to simply load all user messages, which is easiest to do by using `once("value"`:

```
let ref = firebase.database().ref('User-Message').child(this.state.fromUser).child(this.state.toUser);
let message_array = await ref.once('value', async (snapshot) => {
  let messagePromises = [];
  snapshot.forEach(function(userMessageSnapshot) {
    messagePromises.push( firebase.database().ref('Message').child(snapshot.key).once('value', async (payload) => {
      return payload.val();
    })
  })
  await messageSnapshots = Promise.all(messagePromises);
  this.setState({ messages : messageSnapshots })
})
```

---

If you want to get realtime updates, you will have to use an `on()` listener. But that does mean you can't use `async`/`await` in the outer listener. It'd look something like this:

```
let ref = firebase.database().ref('User-Message').child(this.state.fromUser).child(this.state.toUser);
ref.on('value', async (snapshot) => {
  let messagePromises = [];
  snapshot.forEach(function(userMessageSnapshot) {
    messagePromises.push( firebase.database().ref('Message').child(snapshot.key).once('value', async (payload) => {
      return payload.val();
    })
  })
  await messageSnapshots = Promise.all(messagePromises);
  this.setState({ messages : messageSnapshots })
})
```

Comment: will this method keep the state updated with firebase ? i mean what if i sent a message ?

Comment: You need an `on()` listener for that. It'll work fine, just means you can't use promises or `async`/`await`. I added a sample of that too. Note that typos in this code are definitely possible.